# Type parameter extending union type is not narrowed

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I realize there was an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) about this that has been closed but it looks like for my use case this bug still happens. Here's my problem:

I have the following type definitions:

```js
interface typeMap { // for mapping from strings to types
  string  : string;
  number  : number;
  boolean : boolean;
}



type Constructor<T = unknown> = { new (...args: any[]): T };

type ConstructedType<T extends Constructor> = T extends { new(...args: any[]): infer U; }
? U: never;

type PrimitiveOrConstructor = // 'string' | 'number' | 'boolean' | constructor
  | Constructor
  | keyof typeMap;
```

Now I would expect to be able to narrow down any `T extends PrimitiveOrConstructor` but it ends up not working:

```js
// infer the guarded type from a specific case of PrimitiveOrConstructor
type GuardedType<T extends PrimitiveOrConstructor> =
  T extends Constructor
    ? ConstructedType<T>
    : T extends keyof typeMap
      ? typeMap[T]
      : never;

function typeGuard<T extends PrimitiveOrConstructor>(o: unknown, className: T): o is GuardedType<T> {

  const localPrimitiveOrConstructor: PrimitiveOrConstructor = className;

  if (typeof localPrimitiveOrConstructor === 'string') {
    return typeof o === localPrimitiveOrConstructor;
  }

  return o instanceof localPrimitiveOrConstructor;

}
```

If I replace the `localPrimitiveOrConstructor` with the `className` of type `T` it is not narrowed. Even if I define the condition as a type guard, within the if-block `className` is narrowed to `T & keyof typeMap` and outside of it it is still `T` instead of being narrowed to `Constructor`.

Is there something wrong in the implementation that's making the existing fix not apply here?

Comment: How do you use `typeGuard`? I mean wich arguments you use with this function

Comment: You can see some examples [here](https://github.com/StoneCypher/is_a_ts/blob/main/src/ts/tests/blog-claims.spec.ts), for example:


`expect(typeGuard(5, 'number')).toBe(true)

expect(typeGuard(new B(), B)).toBe(true)` (For some `class B {}`)

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use generic:

```js
interface typeMap { // for mapping from strings to types
    string: string;
    number: number;
    boolean: boolean;
}

type Constructor<T = unknown> = { new(...args: any[]): T };

type ConstructedType<T extends Constructor> = T extends { new(...args: any[]): infer U; }
    ? U : never;

type PrimitiveOrConstructor = 
    | Constructor
    | keyof typeMap;

function typeGuard(o: unknown, className: PrimitiveOrConstructor) {

    if (typeof className === 'string') {
        const check = className // keyof typeMap
        return typeof o === className;
    }

    const check = className // Constructor<unknown>

    return o instanceof className;

}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAjATwA4QLJw8gb2QHpjkYB7KZAWzw1AHNyoKbkBnMKJj1C1JggcAUMnGduTAFySeIRgG4xEkAFcaAI2iz1W6MonJNFCgBsIcELJPnLIZQF8RI9FmQBhCiC5Q1CMCoAHgAVZABeZDUQAGsQCgB3EAA%20CMJkEAgEgAoAOny4KEYOWSs0AG0AXQBKWTDHZVchT29ff0gAExChUOQIAA9IEA6%20Lx9udqpUyLCBoZH0zJz83MLi0pAKmtlQGGhkAFVFZGcjAH5D5F0IADcDFzcUAAUeGmAwYDuAeSgxtoCqGkVOIAD4tcZ%20AFQYHIMExCBoCgwQRYXAYRowaIBYDeFEQADiakKHWyFFk0TiiRAABpkAgzHAOBwAHJwGgQWQvYBvD7fX6tCZQ6qEFxGYDI7KPJF0hlM1nsiLhSIAcl8TGVwoIMKMCAFdIAFhAEDE0vTGSy2ShSMh4YjkY80dqJFAIGA1FAQHjpQIlZEzXLLYYJM4YbrxgajSa-bKLQrrX9BYEoEEKfEkslRc7Xe7PQJQFwrEhpf7YxBGs4gA)

Comment: This does answer my question as I asked it, however I did simplify it a bit because I thought it wouldn't matter - `typeGuard` is meant to be generic because it is meant to "extract" which type is constructed by "className". I will edit my question.

Comment: I ended up using this solution but I added two generic overloads to preserve the i
ntended functionality. If you can add these lines I can accept this answer.


`function typeGuard<T extends Constructor>(o: unknown, className: T): o is ConstructedType<T>;
function typeGuard<T extends keyof typeMap>(o: unknown, className: T): o is typeMap[T];`